# How to set a preselected folder for a Java Photoshop Script

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am a scripting Noob but need to change a script i need for work.

The Script takes pictures, edites them in a certain way and puts them into a certain folder.
Right after starting the script, it asks the user to choose a folder to take the pictures from. After that it asks to choose a folder to save the edited pictures to.
Now these two folders always lay in a certain directory.
I want that DialogueBox to start not on the Desktop (like it seems to be set as default) like you can see on the first image.
[image]
 But on a certain subfolder like the one I marked on the second picture.
[image]
I hope you know what I mean: I have to click through all the subfolders each time I run the Script and would like to save me some steps by setting a certain folder for the DialogueBox to pre-open so that i have to choose only one of the few subfolders without going all the way through.

This is the part where I think it has to be set anywhere:

```
// Pops open a dialog for the user to
// choose the folder of documents to process
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Choose folder with pictures to process.");

// Pops open a dialog for the user to
// set the output folder
var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Choose target folder.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested. This is the solution is found out:

```
    / Pops open a dialog for the user to
    // choose the folder of documents to process

    //Startordner einstellen
    var sel_inputFolder = "Z:\!-Workspace";
    var inputFolder = Folder(sel_inputFolder).selectDlg("Ordner mit      Dateien Auswählen die abgearbeitet werden sollen.");

    // Pops open a dialog for the user to
    // set the output folder

    var sel_outputFolder = "Z:\!-Workspace";
    var outputFolder = Folder(sel_outputFolder).selectDlg("Bitte Zielverzeichnis wählen.");
```